# FindAllAsync can't find device on Surface

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I've written a windows store app to test communication with a device via WINUsb.  It works great on the development laptop (Windows 8.1 Preview, VS2013) but not on a Surface.

The device is appearing as expected in Device Manager (under Universal Serial Bus Devices) but my program is not finding it.

I've installed VS2013 on the Surface to test with.  Here is a code snippet:

```cs
    var selector = "System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=" + "{DEE824EF-729B-4A0E-9C14-B7117D33A817}" + " AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True AND System.DeviceInterface.WinUsb.UsbVendorId:=1250 AND System.DeviceInterface.WinUsb.UsbProductId:=5136";

    ObservableCollection<string> propertiesToRetrieve = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    propertiesToRetrieve.Add("System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid");
    propertiesToRetrieve.Add("System.Devices.ContainerId");


    var interfaces = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector, propertiesToRetrieve);

    foreach (DeviceInformation deviceInterface in interfaces)
    {

        //device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInterface.Id);


        var pt = deviceInterface.Properties.GetEnumerator();
        while (pt.MoveNext())
        {
            if (pt.Current.Value != null)
                    tbMsg.Text += string.Format("{0}{1}", (pt.Current.Key + "=" + pt.Current.Value), Environment.NewLine);
        }

    }
```

I've tried different variations of "selector" but it still can't find the device.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks,

Cheri

Comment: Are you sure the device is using the WinUSB driver on Windows RT? You may need to write a custom driver for it that declares the NTARM platform.

Comment: I'm using a Surface Pro...

Comment: You should specify that in the post. "Surface" and "Surface 2" generally denote the RT version. You may still need to [create custom drivers for your device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and install them on the Surface Pro. It's not nearly as hard as it sounds. It basically just needs to point the system to `winusb.sys` when it sees your device.

Answer (score 0):

The AQS filter string needs to match the properties on the device interface.  If they do not, the device information object gets filtered out.  Obviously some of those properties are different on the surface tablet than on your other PC.

I would request all of the properties that you want to use in your filter selector, remove the selector, or remove clauses util it finds the interface you are looking for, and then look at properties.

Once you see what property values are on the interface you were trying to find, then logically evaluate the filter.  Some of the values must be different than you expected.

-Sam